# Crop a video layer in an AVComposition

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation

I'm using `AVMutableComposition` to position and composite two different video tracks for playback and export.  I can easily scale and position the video tracks using `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`. This is all in the sample code.

However, what I need to do is crop one of the video layers. Not "effectively crop" as is done in the sample code by having the video frame overlap the side of the composition, but actually crop one of the layers being composited so the shape of the composited video is different but video is not distorted. In other words, I don't want to change the renderSize of the whole composition, just crop one of the composited layers.

Is this possible? Any ideas to make it happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Cropping Settings?](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009795-CH1-SW14) of AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction?

Comment: Yes thank you. Those routines are new in 10.9 and were not yet available when I asked the question ;)